# can pthread_join be unblockant?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, pthreads, client-server

i have a function like this :

```
void create_serv_and_init_client(client_t *cl, serv_t *serv)
{
    static int i = 0;
    pthread_t thread_serv;

    if (i == 0) {
        *serv = create_serv_socket();
        if (pthread_create(&thread_serv, NULL, waiting_connection, \
        (void *)serv) < 0) {
            perror("could not create thread");
            exit(1);
        }
        pthread_join(thread_serv, NULL);
        cl[0] = create_client(0);
        printf("OK\n");
        i++;
    }
}
```

waiting_connection function :

```
void *waiting_connection(void *server)
{
    serv_t *serv = (serv_t *)server;

    serv->newSocket = accept(serv->sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv->newAddr, \
    &serv->addr_size);
    if (serv->newSocket < 0) {
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((serv->childpid = fork()) == 0) {
        close(serv->sockfd);
        while (recv(serv->newSocket, serv->buffer, 1024, 0) != 0) {
            printf("Client: %s\n", serv->buffer);
            send(serv->newSocket, serv->buffer, strlen(serv->buffer), 0);
            bzero(serv->buffer, sizeof(serv->buffer));
        }
    }
}
```

if i dont pthread_join, i will never receive the sended msg by the client, but however, it will block my program until receiving the message, but i wanna have a unblockant waiting of the client message, so it is possible to do a unblockant waiting, for the reception of the client message ?

Comment: your program is obscure for me, *thread_serv* is the client or the server (I vote for the server but ...) ? Do you speak about *pthread_join(thread_serv, NULL);* or an other *pthread_join* not visible here ? you speak about "waiting of the "client message", it seems you have to look at *select*

Comment: also "if i dont pthread_join, i will never receive the sended msg by the client" and asking for "can pthread_join be unblockant?" seems contradictory. But probably your problem is not about the join, again look at *select* if you exchange messages through a *socket*

Comment: *if i dont pthread_join, i will never receive the sended msg by the client*  You have a bad design.  Rethink how you want to do things.  Welcome to programming - you get into writing something and realize you screwed it all up and have to start over.  If you continue programming, this will not be the last time you will do this.  There are two types of programmers:  those that have written bad code and liars.  ;-)

Comment: Thread_serv is the server, and i'm speaking about the ```pthread_join(thread_serv, NULL); ```, but i can do it like this, but i just dont understand why this is not working actually.. @bruno

Comment: Liars ? Like really ? @AndrewHenle I have to use pthread, because this function loop and i have to wait the message client, so i can't just call the `waiting connection` because it will just block the program behind, aswell...

Comment: @ZahreddineLaidi if you create a thread and immediately wait for its ends it is like to do the thread job directly in the main thread. I do not share the way Andrez Henle speaks but he is right saying you have a problem in your design. How do you receive the client message ? Through socket ? if yes look at *select*, else explain

Comment: i've added the ```waiting_connection``` function, this is a project school, and it is forbiden to use select, this is why i use socket instead @bruno

Comment: @ZahreddineLaidi what the main thread does after the server thread is launch ? why you do not want to be blocked ? For me your question is a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: because this is a game, so the server is launched when the first client is connected to the game, and if my program always wait others input of others plays, the actual players connected can't play, so this need to be unblockant, asynchronous if you want.. @bruno

Comment: @ZahreddineLaidi clearly this is a xy problem, see my answer with a simplified design

Comment: @ZahreddineLaidi so ?

Answer (score 0):

> because this is a game, so the server is launched when the first client is connected to the game, and if my program always wait others input of others plays, the actual players connected can't play, so this need to be unblockant, asynchronous if you want.

So you want one thread per client connection, and to be able to always accept a new client connection. That's sounds about right.

In that case the management of the messages received from a given client must be done in the corresponding thread, not in the main thread. The main thread only manages the client connections and launch the new threads, it does not have to join the other threads.

So the *accept* are done in the main thread, not in the separated threads, and it gives the socket with the new client in argument when it launch the new thread for that client, then *pthread_detach* the new thread.

> ```
> if ((serv->childpid = fork()) == 0) {
>    close(serv->sockfd);
> ```

all of that does not exist, there is no *fork*, you use threads.

---

Of course an other way is to not use threads at all but to *fork*, anyway the roles are unchanged between the initial process and the child processes.

Your problem is that you didn't assign the right roles to everyone.